# Iterating over Rows in many CSV Files and modifying them in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transformation

I am writing a script that is supposed to read a lot of csv files and transform data in a specific column, when the condition is being met.
To do this I have a for-loop that looks like this:

```
for index, transformed_row in transformed_data.iterrows():
        new_rows = []
   
        if transformed_row['Code'] in ['14/9', '14+9', '149']:
            transformed_row['Code'] = '18'
            
        elif transformed_row['Code'] == "3+4+1":
            transformed_row['Code'] = '17'
```

However I read in the Pandas documentation that when using .iterrows() one should not modify the DataFrame. Even though this code works and my output DF is exactly the way I want, I fear that over 50+ csv files this will not always work as stated in the documentation.

So my idea was to make a new list

```
new_rows = []
```

and adding the changed rows there with something like this

```
new_rows.append(transformed_row.copy())
```

however, when I do this, I get duplicates of the rows I want to transform. I cannot find a solution on how to do this properly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simpler and better performing option is to use `Series.replace` ([link](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html)):

```py
replace_dict = {"14/9": "18", "14+9": "18", "149": "18", "3+4+1": "17"}
transformed_data["Code"] = transformed_data["Code"].replace(replace_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're facing with duplicates occurs because you're appending a copy of the entire transformed_row

Here's how you can modify your code.

```
new_rows = []

for index, transformed_row in transformed_data.iterrows():
    new_row = transformed_row.copy()  # Create a copy of the original row
    
    if transformed_row['Code'] in ['14/9', '14+9', '149']:
        new_row['Code'] = '18'
        
    elif transformed_row['Code'] == "3+4+1":
        new_row['Code'] = '17'
    
    new_rows.append(new_row)  # Append the modified row to the new list

# Now you can create a new DataFrame from new_rows
new_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(new_rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think more efficient way is to use apply to change value of column with some condition

```
import pandas as pd

def transform_code(code):
    if code in ['14/9', '14+9', '149']:
        return '18'
    elif code == "3+4+1":
        return '17'
    else:
        return code

transformed_data['Code'] = transformed_data['Code'].apply(transform_code)
```